# ¿Cómo puedo orientar un código a objetos?

Tags: java, poo

tengo un problema, no entiendo la POO y necesito convertir realizar una comprobación de agua.

Tengo que hacer un programa que lea los cuerpos de agua a analizar. Tengo que leer y convertir a array, lee esto: Mallorquin 0 Barranquilla 30
y tiene que quedar separado de esta manera:

Nombre     | Id_cuerpo_agua  |  Municipio     |   IRCA
Mallorquin |        0        |  Barranquilla  |   30

Implementar POO creando una clase llamada CuerpoDeAgua.
Implementar un método dentro de la clase CuerpoDeAgua llamado nivel que calcule el nivel de
riesgo de un cuerpo de agua de acuerdo con los valores de la instancia.

el nivel de riesgo es de la siguiente manera:

0 - 5 SIN RIESGO
5.1 - 14 BAJO
14.1 - 35 MEDIO
35.1 - 80 ALTO
80.1 - 100 INVIABLE SANITARIAMENTE

y por consola tengo que mostrar:

1. los cuerpos de agua que se leyeron
2. mostrar los cuerpos de agua que tienen nivel de riesgo entre medio y alto ósea IRCA entre 14.1 y 80
3. mostrar el nombre de los cuerpos de agua que tienen un nivel de riesgo ALTO separados
   por espacio, en caso de no haber ninguno devolver NA.
4. mostrar la clasificación IRCA promedio de todos los cuerpos de agua ingresados.

de esta manera se lee

1. los cuerpos de agua que se van a leer.
2. Leer la linea(se lee tantas veces como se indique en 1.)

Ejemplo:

Entrada

1. 2(numero de veces que se lee)
2. Mallorquin 0 Barranquilla 30(lectura1)
3. Magdalena 1 Barranquilla 45.3(lectura 2)

la salida tiene que ser:

- Mallorquin(nombre de la primera lectura)
- Magdalena(nombre de la segunda lectura)
- 2.00(numero de cuerpos con promedio entre medio y alto)
- Magdalena(Nombres de cuerpos con nivel de riesgo alto)
- 37.65(promedio de IRCA, en este caso promedio de 30 y 45.3)

El código que tengo es este:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;



public class reto2 {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        
        int n;
        int i;
        String afaz; 
         
        float scma= 0;
        float sumirca = 0; 
        
        java.util.Scanner lea = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("numero de veces a leer");
        n = lea.nextInt();
        

        if(n<=0)
            System.out.println("El valor no es valido");
        else {

            
            
            ArrayList<String> alto = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<String> lugares = new ArrayList<>();
            System.out.println("ingrese lugares");
            
            for(i=1;i<=n;i++) {
                String linea = lea.nextLine();

                String[] arr = linea.split(" ");   
        
                lugares.add(arr[0]);
                String nombre = arr[0];
                /*
                int id = Integer.parseInt(arr[1]);
                String municipio = arr[2];
                */
                float irca = Float.parseFloat(arr[3]);

                

                sumirca = sumirca + irca;
                

                if(14.1<= irca && irca <=80){
                    scma = scma + 1;
                }
                if(35.1 <= irca && irca <=80){
                    alto.add(nombre);
                }

                lea.close();
                


            }
            float promirca = sumirca / n ;
            for (String implug : lugares) {
                System.out.println(implug);
            } 
            System.out.println(scma);
                //n=n-1;
            for (String impalto : alto) {
                System.out.println(impalto);
            } 
            System.out.println(promirca);                
        }          
    }
}
```

Les agradezco mucho su ayuda.

Comment: **1.** Si no entiendes sobre POO puedes empezar leyendo aquí https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programaci%C3%B3n_orientada_a_objetos 
**2.** Qué parte del enunciado es la que no entiendes o donde te trabaste en tu código?

Answer (score 1):

vamos a ver si te muestro un ejemplo

es muy extenso y es totalmente funcional, a ver si con él puedes ir viendo como funciona

primero creamos la clase Lugar, que serán los objetos del arrayList lugares

```
//clase Lugar del arrayList
class Lugar {
    //declaramos las variables de los datos que contendrá el arrayList
    String nombre;
    String ID;
    String municipio;
    double IRCA;
    String nivelRiego;

    //inicializamos las variables vacías
    public Lugar(){
        nombre = "";
        ID = "";
        municipio = "";
        IRCA = 0;
        nivelRiego = "";
    }
    //métodos set
    public void setNombre(String Nombre) {
        this.nombre = Nombre;
    }    
    public void setID(String Id) {
        this.ID = Id;
    }    
    public void setMunicipio(String Municipio) {
        this.municipio = Municipio;
    }
    public void setIRCA(double Irca) {
        this.IRCA = Irca;
    }    
    public void setNivelRiego(String NivelRiego) {
        this.nivelRiego = NivelRiego;
    }
    //métodos get
    public String getNombre() {
        return this.nombre;
    }    
    public String getID() {
        return this.ID;
    }    
    public String getMunicipio() {
    return this.municipio;
    }
    public double getIRCA() {
        return this.IRCA;
    }    
    public String getNivelRiego() {
        return this.nivelRiego;
    }
}
```

La clase cuerpo de Agua que selecciona el nivel de riesgo

```
public class CuerpoDeAgua {
//método que selecciona el nivel de riego
    public String nivelDeRiego(double nivel){
    
        //el nivel de riesgo es de la siguiente manera:
        //0 - 5 SIN RIESGO 
        //5.1 - 14 BAJO 
        //14.1 - 35 MEDIO 
        //35.1 - 80 ALTO 
        //80.1 - 100 INVIABLE SANITARIAMENTE
    
        //declaramos la variable string vacía
        String nivelRiego = "";
    
        //condicionales de si está ente los márgenes marcados que indique una u otra opción
        if (nivel < 0){
            nivelRiego = "Error Min";
        }
        else if ((nivel >= 0) && (nivel <= 5)){
            nivelRiego = "SIN RIESGO";
        }
        else if ((nivel >= 5.1) && (nivel <= 14)){
            nivelRiego = "BAJO";
        }
        else if ((nivel >= 14.1) && (nivel <= 35)){
            nivelRiego = "MEDIO";
        }
        else if ((nivel >= 35.1) && (nivel <= 80)){
            nivelRiego = "ALTO";
        }
        else if ((nivel >= 80.1) && (nivel <= 100)){
            nivelRiego = "INVIABLE SANITARIAMENTE";
        }
        else if (nivel > 100){
            nivelRiego = "Error Max";
        }
        //retornamos el valor de la variable
        return nivelRiego;
    }
}
```

La clase estación de agua con el método main

```
public class EstacionDeAguas {
    //private static Object lugar;
    static ArrayList<Lugar> lugares = new ArrayList<>();
    //instanciamos clase escaner
    static Scanner lea = new Scanner(System.in); 

    //método main
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {   
        //al iniciar el programa llamamos al método mostrar menú
        metodoMostrarMenu();
    }
    //método que uestra las estaciones de agua con todos los datos introducidos por teclado
    private static void metodoMostrarEstacionesAgua(ArrayList<Lugar> lugares) {
        System.out.println("Las estaciones de Agua registradas son:");
        //bucle que recorre el arrayList
        for (int i = 0; i < lugares.size(); i++){
            //con el método get del arrayList accedemos a cada dato (columna) de cada registro (linea)
            //para ello llamamos al arrayList lugares, usamos el get para extraer el dato, y luego le decimos que dato deseamos
            System.out.println(lugares.get(i).getNombre() + ", " + lugares.get(i).getID() + ", " +
                lugares.get(i).getMunicipio() + ", "+ lugares.get(i).getIRCA());
        }
        //método para continuar el programa o cerrarlo
        metodoContinuarPrograma();
    }
    //metodo que muestra las estaciones de agua con el nivel de riesgo calculado
    private static void metodoMostrarEstacionesAguaConNivelDeRiego(ArrayList<Lugar> lugares) {
        System.out.println("Estaciones de Agua y Nivel de Riego :");
        for (int i = 0; i < lugares.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(lugares.get(i).getNombre() + ", " + lugares.get(i).getID() + ", " +
            lugares.get(i).getMunicipio() + ", "+ lugares.get(i).getIRCA() + ", " +
                lugares.get(i).getNivelRiego());
        }
        metodoContinuarPrograma();
    } 
    //estaciones que no tienen riesgo
    private static void metodoMostrarEstacionesAguaSinRiesgo(ArrayList<Lugar> lugares) {
        System.out.println("Estaciones de Agua sin Riesgo de Riego :");
        for (int i = 0; i < lugares.size(); i++){
            if (lugares.get(i).getNivelRiego().equals("SIN RIESGO")){
                System.out.println(lugares.get(i).getNombre() + ", " + lugares.get(i).getID() + ", " +
                lugares.get(i).getMunicipio() + ", "+ lugares.get(i).getIRCA() + ", " +
                    lugares.get(i).getNivelRiego());
            }
        }
        metodoContinuarPrograma();
    }
    //estaciones con riesgo bajo
    private static void metodoMostrarEstacionesAguaConRiesgoBajo(ArrayList<Lugar> lugares) {
        System.out.println("Estaciones de Agua con Nivel de Riego Bajo :");
        for (int i = 0; i < lugares.size(); i++){
            if (lugares.get(i).getNivelRiego().equals("BAJO")){
                System.out.println(lugares.get(i).getNombre() + ", " + lugares.get(i).getID() + ", " +
                lugares.get(i).getMunicipio() + ", "+ lugares.get(i).getIRCA() + ", " +
                    lugares.get(i).getNivelRiego());
            }
        }
        metodoContinuarPrograma();
    }
    //estaciones con riesgo medio
    private static void metodoMostrarEstacionesAguaConRiesgoMedio(ArrayList<Lugar> lugares) {
        System.out.println("Estaciones de Agua con Nivel de Riego Medio:");
        for (int i = 0; i < lugares.size(); i++){
            if (lugares.get(i).getNivelRiego().equals("MEDIO")){
                System.out.println(lugares.get(i).getNombre() + ", " + lugares.get(i).getID() + ", " +
                lugares.get(i).getMunicipio() + ", "+ lugares.get(i).getIRCA() + ", " +
                    lugares.get(i).getNivelRiego());
            }
        }
        metodoContinuarPrograma();
    }
    //estaciones con riesgo alto
    private static void metodoMostrarEstacionesAguaConRiesgoAlto(ArrayList<Lugar> lugares) {
        System.out.println("Estaciones de Agua con Nivel de Riego Alto:");
        for (int i = 0; i < lugares.size(); i++){
            if (lugares.get(i).getNivelRiego().equals("ALTO")){
                System.out.println(lugares.get(i).getNombre() + ", " + lugares.get(i).getID() + ", " +
                lugares.get(i).getMunicipio() + ", "+ lugares.get(i).getIRCA() + ", " +
                    lugares.get(i).getNivelRiego());
            }
        }
        metodoContinuarPrograma();
    }
    //estaciones con riesgo inviable
    private static void metodoMostrarEstacionesAguaConRiesgoInviable(ArrayList<Lugar> lugares) {
        System.out.println("Estaciones de Agua con Nivel de Riego Inviable Sanitariamente:");
        for (int i = 0; i < lugares.size(); i++){
            if (lugares.get(i).getNivelRiego().equals("INVIABLE SANITARIAMENTE")){
                System.out.println(lugares.get(i).getNombre() + ", " + lugares.get(i).getID() + ", " +
                lugares.get(i).getMunicipio() + ", "+ lugares.get(i).getIRCA() + ", " +
                    lugares.get(i).getNivelRiego());
            }
        }
        metodoContinuarPrograma();
    }
    //método que muestra el nombre de las estaciones de agua
    private static void metodoMostrarEstacionesAguaNombre(ArrayList<Lugar> lugares) {
        System.out.println("Estaciones de Agua por Nombre :");
        for (int i = 0; i < (lugares.size() - 1); i++){
            System.out.print(lugares.get(i).getNombre() + ", ");
        }
        System.out.println(lugares.get(lugares.size() - 1).getNombre());
        metodoContinuarPrograma();
    }
    //método que mustra las estaciones con riesgo alto por su nombre
    private static void metodoMostrarEstacionesAguaConRiesgoAltoNombre(ArrayList<Lugar> lugares) {
        System.out.println("Estaciones de Agua Por Nombre y Nivel de Riego Alto:");
        for (int i = 0; i < lugares.size(); i++){
            if (lugares.get(i).getNivelRiego().equals("ALTO")){
                System.out.println(lugares.get(i).getNombre() + ", " + lugares.get(i).getNivelRiego());
            }
        }
        metodoContinuarPrograma();
    }
    //estaciones de agua por nombre con su IRCA
    private static void metodoMostrarEstacionesAguaNombreIRCA(ArrayList<Lugar> lugares) {
        System.out.println("Estaciones de Agua por Nombre e IRCA :");
        for (int i = 0; i < lugares.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(lugares.get(i).getNombre() + ", " + lugares.get(i).getIRCA());
        }
        metodoContinuarPrograma();
    }
    //método que calcula el promedio del IRCA
    private static void metodoMostrarPromedioIRCA(ArrayList<Lugar> lugares) {
        //variable para el promedio
        double promedio = 0;
        System.out.print("El Promedio IRCA es de: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < lugares.size(); i++){
            //varibale que acumula el irca de cada registro
            promedio += lugares.get(i).getIRCA();
        }
        //resultado de dividir la acumulación de la suma del IRCA entre el número de registros
        System.out.println(promedio / lugares.size());
        metodoContinuarPrograma();
    }
    //método para introducir registros
    private static void metodoIntroducirRegistros(){

        //Instalaciamos la clase CuerpoDeAgua
        CuerpoDeAgua miCuerpo = new CuerpoDeAgua();
        //variables para los contadores
        int contador = 0, numReg = 0;
        //pedimos el número de registros a introducir
        System.out.println("Introduzca el número de registros a grabar: ");
        //almacenamos el número de registros
        numReg = lea.nextInt();
        //limpiamos el búfer del teclado
        lea.nextLine();
    
        //mientras el contador sea mayor que el número de registros a introducir, hace el bucle
        while (contador < numReg){
            //declaramos un objeto de la clase Lugar
            Lugar miLugar = new Lugar();
            //pedimos los datos a introducir
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("Por favor, introduzca el Nombre del Registro " + (contador + 1) + ": ");
            String nombre = lea.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Facilite su ID para " + nombre + ": ");
            String ID = lea.nextLine();
            System.out.println("En que Municipio e encuentra " + nombre + ": ");
            String municipio = lea.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Su IRCA es de: ");
            double IRCA = lea.nextDouble();
            //al ser el último dato un double, limpiamos el búfer del teclado
            lea.nextLine();
        
            //almacenamos los datos de las variables en el arrayList por medio del método set
            miLugar.setNombre(nombre);
            miLugar.setID(ID);
            miLugar.setMunicipio(municipio);
            miLugar.setIRCA(IRCA);
            String nivelRiego = miCuerpo.nivelDeRiego(IRCA);
            miLugar.setNivelRiego(nivelRiego);
            lugares.add(miLugar);
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------");
            //aumentamos el contador
            contador++;
        }
        metodoContinuarPrograma();
    }
    //método que muestra menú
    public static void metodoMostrarMenu(){
        //variable entera para la selección
        int eleccion = 0;
    
        //imprimimos opciones generales
        System.out.println();
    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Menú (Elija una opción");
        System.out.println("1 - Opciones sobre Registros");
        System.out.println("2 - Opciones sobre Cuerpos de Agua");
        System.out.println("3 - Opciones sobre Nivel de Riego");
        System.out.println("4 - Cáculos con IRCA");
        System.out.println("5 - Opciones sobre programa");
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Su elección es: ");
        eleccion = lea.nextInt();
        //al meter valor númerico limpiamos el búfer
        lea.nextLine();
    
        //hacemos una selección con el valor introducido por teclado de la opción elegida
        switch (eleccion){
                //en función de la elección mostramos el submenú elegido
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("-----------Opciones sobre Registros--------------------------------------");
                    System.out.println("11 - Introducir Registros");
                    System.out.println("12 - Eliminar un Registro");
                    System.out.println("13 - Editar un Registro");
                    System.out.println("14 - Eliminar todos los Registros");
                    System.out.println("15 - Volver");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("-----------Opciones sobre Cuerpos de Agua--------------------------------");
                    System.out.println("21 - Ver Cuerpos de Agua");
                    System.out.println("22 - Ver Cuerpos de Agua y Nivel de Riego");
                    System.out.println("23 - Mostrar el nombre de todos los Cuerpos de Agua");
                    System.out.println("24 - Volver");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("-----------Opciones sobre Nivel de Riego---------------------------------");
                    System.out.println("31 - Ver Cuerpos de Agua con nivel de Riego 'SIN RIESGO'");
                    System.out.println("32 - Ver Cuerpos de Agua con nivel de Riego 'BAJO'");
                    System.out.println("33 - Ver Cuerpos de Agua con nivel de Riego 'MEDIO'");
                    System.out.println("34 - Ver Cuerpos de Agua con nivel de Riego 'ALTO'");
                    System.out.println("35 - Ver Cuerpos de Agua con nivel de Riego 'INVIABLE SANITARIAMENTE'");            
                    System.out.println("36 - Mostrar el nombre de los cuerpos de Agua con Nivel de Riego Alto");
                    System.out.println("37 - Mostrar Nombre y medida de IRCA");
                    System.out.println("38 - Volver");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    System.out.println("-----------Cáculos con IRCA----------------------------------------------");
                    System.out.println("41 - Mostrar promedio de todos los registros IRCA");
                    System.out.println("42 - Volver");
                    break;
                //--------------------------------------------------------------
                case 5:
                    System.out.println("-----------Opciones sobre programa---------------------------------------");
                    System.out.println("51 - Cerrar Programa");
                    System.out.println("52 - Volver");
                    break;
                //en caso de meter cualquier otro valor no contemplado, inicia el programa
                default:
                    metodoMostrarMenu();
                    break;
            }
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("Su elección es: ");
            eleccion = lea.nextInt();
            //limpiamos el búfer
            lea.nextLine();
        
            //si alguna de las opciones elegida en cualquiera de los submenús, es la de volver, le damos el valor 100 a la variable eleccion
            if ((eleccion == 15) || (eleccion == 24) || (eleccion == 38) || (eleccion == 42) || (eleccion == 52)){
                eleccion = 100;
            }
    
            //en función del valor elegido en las opciones motramos el método aecuado
        switch (eleccion){
            case 11:
                metodoIntroducirRegistros();
                break;
            case 12:
                metodoEliminarUnRegistro(lugares);
                break;
            case 13:
                metodoEditarUnRegistro(lugares);
                break;
            case 14:
                metodoEliminarRegistros(lugares);
                break;
            //--------------------------------------------------------------
            case 21:
                metodoMostrarEstacionesAgua(lugares);
                break;
            case 22:
                metodoMostrarEstacionesAguaConNivelDeRiego(lugares);
                break;
            case 23:
                metodoMostrarEstacionesAguaNombre(lugares);
                break;
            //--------------------------------------------------------------    
            case 31:
                metodoMostrarEstacionesAguaSinRiesgo(lugares);
                break;
            case 32:
                metodoMostrarEstacionesAguaConRiesgoBajo(lugares);
                break;
            case 33:
                metodoMostrarEstacionesAguaConRiesgoMedio(lugares);
            break;
            case 34:
                metodoMostrarEstacionesAguaConRiesgoAlto(lugares);
                break;
                case 35:
                    metodoMostrarEstacionesAguaConRiesgoInviable(lugares);
                break;                
            case 36:
                metodoMostrarEstacionesAguaConRiesgoAltoNombre(lugares);
                break;
            case 37:
                metodoMostrarEstacionesAguaNombreIRCA(lugares);
                break;
            //--------------------------------------------------------------
            case 41:
                metodoMostrarPromedioIRCA(lugares);
                break;
            //--------------------------------------------------------------
            case 51:
                System.out.println("Que pase un buen día");
                System.exit(0);
                break;
            case 100:
                metodoMostrarMenu();
                break;
            default:
                metodoMostrarMenu();
                break;
            }
        }
        //método que elimina un regstro
        private static void metodoEliminarUnRegistro(ArrayList<Lugar> lugares) {
            int indice = lugares.size();
            Lugar miLugarR = new Lugar();
            //mostramos el nombre de los registros
            System.out.println("Actualmente existen " + indice + " registros, sus nombres son: ");
            System.out.println("Estaciones de Agua por Nombre :");
            for (int i = 0; i < (lugares.size() - 1); i++){
                System.out.print(lugares.get(i).getNombre() + ", ");
            }
            System.out.println(lugares.get(lugares.size() - 1).getNombre());
            //pedimos el nombre del registro a eliminar
            System.out.println("Por favor, indique el nombre del registro a eliminar: ");
            String nombre = lea.nextLine();
            //recorremos el arrayList
            for (int i = 0; i < lugares.size(); i++){
                //cuando el nombre del cuerpo de agua, coincida con el nombre dado por teclado
                if (lugares.get(i).getNombre().equals(nombre)){
                    System.out.println("Registro eliminado con éxito");
                    //usamos el método remove para eliminarlo
                    lugares.remove(i);                       
                }
            }
            metodoContinuarPrograma();
        }
        //método que edita un registro
        private static void metodoEditarUnRegistro(ArrayList<Lugar> lugares) {
            int indice = lugares.size();
            Lugar miLugarR = new Lugar();
            CuerpoDeAgua miCuerpo = new CuerpoDeAgua();
    
            System.out.println("Actualmente existen " + indice + " registros, sus nombres son: ");
            System.out.println("Estaciones de Agua por Nombre :");
            for (int i = 0; i < (lugares.size() - 1); i++){
                System.out.print(lugares.get(i).getNombre() + ", ");
            }
            System.out.println(lugares.get(lugares.size() - 1).getNombre());
            System.out.println("Que Registro desea modificar, ponga su nombre: ");
            String nombreMod = lea.nextLine();
    
            System.out.println("Desea modificar el Nombre del Registro ? s/n");
            String nom = lea.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Desea modificar su ID ? s/n");
            String id = lea.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Desea modificar el Municipio del Registro ? s/n");
            String mun = lea.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Desea modificar su IRCA ? s/n");
            String irca = lea.nextLine();
    
            for (int i = 0; i < lugares.size(); i++){
                if (lugares.get(i).getNombre().equals(nombreMod)){
                    if (nom.equals("s")){
                        System.out.println("Ponga el nuevo nombre para el registro");
                        String nombre = lea.nextLine();
                        lugares.get(1).setNombre(nombre);
                    }
                    if (id.equals("s")){
                        System.out.println("Ponga el nuevo ID para el registro");
                        String ID = lea.nextLine();
                        lugares.get(1).setID(ID);
                    }
                    if (mun.equals("s")){
                        System.out.println("Ponga el nuevo Municipio para el registro");
                        String municipio = lea.nextLine();
                        lugares.get(1).setMunicipio(municipio);
                }
                if (irca.equals("s")){
                    System.out.println("Ponga el nuevo IRCA para el registro");
                    double IRCA = lea.nextDouble();
                    lea.nextLine();
                    lugares.get(1).setIRCA(IRCA);
                    String nivelRiego = miCuerpo.nivelDeRiego(IRCA);
                    lugares.get(1).setNivelRiego(nivelRiego);
                }
            }
        }
        metodoContinuarPrograma();
    }
    //método que elimina todos los registros
    private static void metodoEliminarRegistros(ArrayList<Lugar> lugares)     {
        int indice = lugares.size();
        Lugar miLugarR = new Lugar();
        System.out.println("Actualmente existen " + indice + " registros, sus nombres son: ");
        System.out.println("Estaciones de Agua por Nombre :");
        for (int i = 0; i < (lugares.size() - 1); i++){
            System.out.print(lugares.get(i).getNombre() + ", ");
        }
        System.out.println(lugares.get(lugares.size() - 1).getNombre());
        System.out.println("Por favor, indique el nombre del registro a eliminar: ");
        String nombre = lea.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Registros eliminados con éxito");
        for (int i = 0; i < lugares.size(); i++){
            lugares.remove(i);                       
        }
        metodoContinuarPrograma();
    }
    //método que selecciona la continuación del programa o lo cierra
    private static void metodoContinuarPrograma() {
        System.out.println("Para seguir teclee s, si no, cualquier otra tecla para salir");
        String decision = lea.nextLine();
        if (decision.equals("s")){
            metodoMostrarMenu();
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Que pase un buen día");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Si no es mucha molestia para el comunero que ha votado mi respuesta en negativo, me gustaría que expusiera el motivo para tenerlo en cuenta en mis próximas respuestas o corregir ésta. Un saludo

Comment: Pues si que llama la atención que una respuesta funcional, comentada y que a mi juicio está bien estructurada, reciba un voto negativo. No estaría de más que se diera un explicación de la razón de ese voto negativo.